"Unable to find git in your PATH" error while trying to make a flutter build using Jenkins
I'm trying to make a flutter build using Jenkins.
Before running, the flutter command apparently calls shared.bat, which is located in flutter/bin.
REM Check that git exists and get the revision
  SET git_exists=false
  2>NUL (
    PUSHD "%flutter_root%"
    FOR /f %%r IN ('git rev-parse HEAD') DO (
      SET git_exists=true
      SET revision=%%r
    )
    POPD
  )
  REM If git didn't execute we don't have git. Exit without /B to avoid retrying.
  if %git_exists% == false echo Error: Unable to find git in your PATH. && EXIT 1

I tried to edit this batch file and the git rev-parse HEAD command runs without errors, I also tried to run this command in papeline jenkins, the result is the same. The problem is that the git_exists variable refuses to be set to true. I've already racked my brain why it works this way.
here is my pipeline code:
pipeline {
    agent any
    environment {
        BUILD_DIR = 'E:\\WORK\\me.develop.projects\\grand_train_lite'
    }
    stages {
        stage('build') {
            steps {
                script {
                    echo "build..."
                        
                    bat '''
                    chcp 1251
                    SET git_exists=false
  2>NUL (
    PUSHD "%flutter_root%"
    FOR /f %%r IN ('git rev-parse HEAD') DO (
      SET git_exists=true
       echo 'After2 : %git_exists%'
      SET revision=%%r
    )
    POPD
  )
 echo 'After1 : %git_exists%'
                    flutter doctor
                    '''

                    dir(BUILD_DIR) {
                        if (params.BUILD_TYPE == 'debug') {
                            echo "DEBUG"
                            //pubversion build
                            //bat "echo %PATH%"
                            //bat "pubversion build"
                        }


                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

output:
C:\ProgramData\Jenkins\.jenkins\workspace\grandtrain lite>chcp 1251 
Текущая кодовая страница: 1251

C:\ProgramData\Jenkins\.jenkins\workspace\grandtrain lite>SET git_exists=false 

C:\ProgramData\Jenkins\.jenkins\workspace\grandtrain lite>(
PUSHD "C:\Users\kompo\AppData\Local\flutter"  
 FOR /F %r IN ('git rev-parse HEAD') DO (
SET git_exists=true  
 echo 'After2 : false'  
 SET revision=%r 
)  
 POPD
) 2>NUL 

C:\ProgramData\Jenkins\.jenkins\workspace\grandtrain lite>echo 'After1 : false' 
'After1 : false'

C:\ProgramData\Jenkins\.jenkins\workspace\grandtrain lite>flutter doctor 
Error: Unable to find git in your PATH. 

How do I fix this error?

The problem is pretty straight forward: the directory where the git binary is is not included in PATH (of whatever environment the script is running on). You can either set the environment so that the directory is in PATH or you can use the full path to the git binary instead in the script. Take you pick

When you say that git command works, how did you run it? In a Git Bash shell, or in a cmd shell? It's possible you have Git on your PATH in the environment where you're working, but that it's not visible on the PATH that your script sees. The test I would do is open cmd, and see if git works there, and if not fix the PATH until it does.
